How do academics handle a hit to research productivity due to academic mobility?
This year I moved to a new country for a postdoc. Arranging mine and my partner’s life here has been taking so much of my time and mental space that I have been at a really low productivity for months now. Right now, 25% of my postdoc appointment has passed and I’ve only been able to gain a shallow overview of a couple of research areas that I might tackle in the future. I’ve made no concrete progress in anything.
I have very limited time or focus to dive deep into anything and this is due to all the arrangements I need/needed to do in this new country. There’s been many administrative things to do like applying for work permits, finding a new health insurance, opening bank accounts, finding a new health clinic and scheduling my first visits with new doctors to transfer medical data, handling tax from the previous country we’ve lived in, etc, etc... I also needed to support my partner in their job search. In the last four weeks, I’ve spent about 100 hours hunting for an apartment for rent. We've moved to an area that has a completely messed up housing situation. Thankfully, my employer offered me and my partner an apartment for one year. But now that this time is coming to an end, I’m intensely looking for a new place. This requires me having my email open all day to immediately react to alerts about new properties. (If you’re not quick, you won’t make it to the viewing.) That is, even when I’m in the office, I get constantly distracted by alerts. And then I can’t work the required 8 hours a day because I need to go to a nearby town to do apartment viewings. When I come back home, I feel completely drained and all I can do is submit apartment applications and go to sleep. I have been completely unproductive at work in the last month because of this. Whenever I pick up a publication that I would like to understand deeply, my brain is so scattered that I just can’t focus on understanding it. The stress due to life in a new country is another factor that impacts my cognitive ability. Things that I used to be able to understand quickly, like understanding code, now take forever. Sometimes I give up altogether, and move on to doing an easy thing just to do at least something productive. I also needed to start seeing a therapist regularly because of this.
I know that in the ideal case, I would eliminate all distractions and fully focus on my research. I've been able to do that in my PhD. But right now, it feel like I have no choice, those are all things that need doing. My partner is helping me of course, but still my share of the load is big.
I became really worried that I can't focus on my research because I plan to stay in academia and I was hoping to have a few more publications out of my postdoc appointment.
So my questions are: Do all academics suffer a months-long hit to research productivity after academic mobility? More importantly: What strategies do academics implement to mitigate the hit? And: Are institutions generally understanding of this situation such that I won't get fired from my current position? Will I be able to explain my reduced productivity to my next employer? Are faculty search committees generally understanding of this when they see that a candidate has moved countries in the course of their career?

Good that you are seeing a therapist. Unfortunately all of your questions have answers that depend on personal and situational aspects. Everyone is different. Every situation is different. Something that works for others may be counterproductive for you. I suspect people muddle through or fail to do so. Good luck.

Is your partner supporting you by sharing these tasks? Having moved overseas for a postdoc (admittedly without a partner), this stuff was a pain but nowhere near as burdensome as you seem to be experiencing. My guess is it all is a symptom, not a cause. Get mental health help asap.

What country did you move to?

@Jon Custer, yes, my partner is supportive as much as they can. Their work schedule is much less flexible than mine, e.g. cannot leave work in the middle of the day, while I can, so some tasks only I can do. We have no friends or family here who could help us.

@fedja, I prefer not to disclose.

Up to you. If it is the USA, I, probably, could give you some advice on how to handle the everyday issues, but if it is, say, China, I have no idea whatsoever. In general the answer to your main question is that all depends on the particular circumstances and that all you describe is still below what you'll experience in the first year after your first child is born (unless everything goes very smoothly), but yeah, such things can knock you out for a while and there is nothing unusual about that...

@fedja, thanks, it's a Western country. That's reassuring to hear, though I know that one can mention a birth of a child when applying for faculty positions as an item for search committees to take into account when evaluating applicants, sometimes there's an explicit question for that (I've seen this having applied for a few). But do academics also explain their mobility-related hit to productivity?

@user166265 I'll be honest, I wouldn't. Put yourself in a search committee's shoes - if a candidate said that their postdoc was unproductive because they had to move to a different country, would you count this as a plus? It's hard to spin this so that it doesn't sound like a bad excuse.

Your description of the problems you are experiencing with reduced productivity due to geographical relocation sounds much worse than anything I’ve ever experienced myself or heard about from anyone doing a postdoc (including people who move with children, which presents significant additional complications that it sounds like you don’t have to deal with).
Is moving countries a challenge? Certainly it is — mentally, financially, and logistically. But in the academic context of postdocs it’s not really supposed to be this much of a challenge.
To be clear, I don’t mean to negate or invalidate your experience. Everyone’s situation is unique, and it’s possible you really do need to deal with challenges that no one I know has had. But you ask if all academics experience difficulties like the ones you’re experiencing. I would say, no, far from it.
So, as a first step in figuring out how to deal with the situation it may be worth re-evaluating your assessment that it is really the move to a new place that is the underlying cause (or the only cause, or the primary cause) for your low productivity. If you are misdiagnosing the cause it will be much harder to address the problem effectively.
You may also want to reassess whether your productivity is in fact as abnormally low as you perceive it to be. Starting a postdoc normally means delving into some new research areas, which requires a large upfront investment of time. The rewards often come only later (say in the second year of the postdoc), making productivity in the initial investment period appear low or even zero. Again, without knowing the particular details of the situation it’s impossible to say whether you’re really behind, or whether you’re doing just fine or even better than just fine. I’m just suggesting avenues for exploration and some sanity checks you could try to do to see if you are diagnosing the problem correctly. Talking to your postdoc mentor and/or other experienced colleagues who are more familiar with your discipline and its expectations for researchers at your career stage might lead to a more accurate understanding of the issue.
Other than that, to the extent that your difficulties are really related to the geographic move, I can’t think of any specific strategies for dealing with the problem other than just to work out the logistics as fast and expediently as possible. Good luck!

Thank you, this answer is very useful to me, especially your last point. I did change fields during my postdoc and I could be confusing the slower progress due to learning the new field with the impact of all the life arrangements (albeit they will continue to take a lot of my time until I secure an apartment). A mentor of mine once recommended that I aim to have 2 publications/year during my postdoc to be competitive in faculty applications. I now begin to see that there's no chance for a publication in my first year. But from what you say, this could be a normal course of events.


Do all academics suffer a months-long hit to research productivity after academic mobility?

No. It is normal and expected that people need some time after moving to sort out their private affairs. However, this usually entails things like leaving early a few times in the first weeks to look at apartments, spending a morning at the tax or visa office a few times, or being absent for two hours a week due to language courses, not the drastically reduced job performance over multiple months you describe.

Are institutions generally understanding of this situation such that I won't get fired from my current position? Will I be able to explain my reduced productivity to my next employer? Are faculty search committees generally understanding of this when they see that a candidate has moved countries in the course of their career?

I'm not saying you are not doing the best you can, but it's certainly not normal and, realistically, it will be difficult to convince people who were not in your shoes that this was unavoidable. Your current employer may or may not be understanding (since, presumably, they have a more direct account of what you are doing all day, and are in a better position to judge if your delays are indeed not your fault), but future employers and particularly faculty search committees will likely not be. Many people (realistically, almost everybody) move one to n times early in their career, this will not fly as ""extenuating circumstances".
The good news is that, at least in my field, an unproductive postdoc by itself isn't as much of a red flag as you seem to think it is. Moving into a new research group and, oftentimes, field of research often leads to a phase of drastically reduced productivity, independently of any other circumstances. If you had a good PhD even a postdoc that may have been rather underwhelming may still leave you in a decent position. Of course, if your PhD was not great either, a bad postdoc is likely to end your academic career. In this case it may realistically be time to look at other options.

What strategies do academics implement to mitigate the hit?

There isn't really a silver bullet. Realistically, for most people it's a combination of privilege (as usual, having a bit of money makes things less stressful, because you can hire people to do things for you or stay in a long-stay hotel for a while), help (most importantly from their partners), overwork (work in the night and on the weekend after an afternoon of apartment hunting), and good old luck.
Here in Sweden, many international postdocs try to avoid the problem altogether by leaving their partners / families at home until they themselves have settled (oftentimes for months to years).
I understand that this answer is probably not what you are looking for, but you are asking for how other people handle it, and in my experience that's it...

Available research time commonly waxes and wanes based on life events
This is an inherent part of an academic research career that will occur for anyone with any type of life outside of their job.  In your case you are affected by a move to another country (and all the related administration and setup) as well as helping your partner.  For other people, they will be affected by all sorts of other life events: marital breakdowns, children getting sick, caring for elderly parents, institutional moves, etc.  These are the natural ups-and-downs of life and they will always involve an impact to the time you have available for your research.
Since it involves deep thinking, contemplation, and complex thought and analysis, academic research is an activity that generally requires some substantial unbroken blocks of regular time to do effectively.  My advice in your present situation is to put your research aside entirely and focus on powering through other administrative and personal projects to get settled in your new country.  Once you are settled you will then be able to devote yourself to your research in the larger blocks of time that then become available.
In regard to your questions, yes, virtually all academics suffer from months long hits to their research productivity due to life events.  Universities do not care about (or even notice) small periods of unproductive time where research is put on hiatus --- they care about your long-term research track record over years (at least).  It is only when your long-term research productivity is negatively impacted that you will require any explanation either for your present institution or a future employer.

While this is true, I feel it's fair to say that the start of your postdoc is also a rather bad time to have a phase of waning research productivity. The way early-stage academia is set up, there will be no "long-term" if you are unproductive right now.
